# MySQL restrict results by standard deviation of COUNT(*)

Tags: mysql, count, standard-deviation

I have a table that stores text tags for different kinds of media.  Each piece of media can have multiple tags, and can have the same tag more than once.  What I'm trying to do is return all tags for a piece of media that have a count within one standard deviation of the mean count.

For example: Image1 has four tags - large,blue,large,small,blue.

The results I'm looking for are: large,blue - because there are two "large", and two "blue", but only one "small", which is more than one std away from the mean count.

Make sense?  I can't seem to accomplish this with one query.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

A CTE would be nice, but seeing as they don't exist in MySQL you could separate the problem out to several sub-selects.

In the following example, change the dev.a +-2 to whatever deviation you're after.

```
select b.*
from bob b
inner join (
    select tag, count(tag) cnt
    from bob
    group by tag
) cnt on cnt.tag = b.tag
inner join (
    select avg(cnt) a from (
        select tag, count(tag) cnt
        from bob
        group by tag
    ) dev
) dev on cnt.cnt between (dev.a - 2) and (dev.a + 2)
```

Comment: Hmm, seems as convoluted as I was expecting.  Might just stick with grabbing the data and doing the math via php.

Comment: True.. if you could create a cte then it would be marginally "prettier", but only marginally.